# request.POST has data but save method does not update the db in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to perform below process in my Django application:

Adding member to 'Member' table whenever a user registers.
Creating tasks to populate 'Task' table.
Allocating the 'unallocated tasks' to member and hence populating Allocation table.

I see the data submitted is passed through request.POST but my table is not updated with the same data.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.



class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    DESIGNATION = [
        ('Developer', 'Developer'),
        ('Tester', 'Tester'),
        ('Support', 'Support'),
        ]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, choices=DESIGNATION)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class Task(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = [
        ( 'Low', 'Low'),
        ('Medium', 'Medium'),
        ('Urgent', 'Urgent'),
        ]

    STATUS = [
        ('Not Started', 'Not Started'),
        ('In Progress', 'In Progress'),
        ('Completed', 'Completed'),
        ]
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=CATEGORY)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    member = models.ForeignKey('Member', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    task_status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS)



    def __str__(self):
        return self.name




class Allocation(models.Model):
    
    member = models.ForeignKey('Member', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    task = models.OneToOneField('Task', null=True, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task.name
```

views.py

```
def allocate_task(request):
    try:
        unallocated_tasks = Task.objects.get(member__isnull=True)
    except Task.DoesNotExist:
        unallocated_tasks = None

    if unallocated_tasks == None:
        return redirect('error')
    else:
        form = TaskAllocateForm(instance=unallocated_tasks)

        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = TaskAllocateForm(request.POST, instance=unallocated_tasks)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('/')


    context = {
    'form':form,
    }


    return render(request, 'ttt/allocate_task.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class TaskAllocateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task 
        fields = '__all__'
```

html file

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

{% csrf_token %}

<p> Allocate tasks </p>

{{ form.as_table }}

<input type="submit" name="Submit"></input>


</form>
```

Does it have to do something with my model definitions of **Allocation model**??

Comment: Have you checked that the form is indeed valid?

Comment: Yes, I tried with below code to check the form: ```if form.is_valid() form.save() else: print(form.errors)``` . I did not get any errors in console

Comment: What is in `request.POST`? What is in `unallocated_tasks` (which the name suggests are multiple tasks, but the code suggests it is 1 task)? How far/where in your views code does the process get (e.g., use print functions with the development server to find out)?

Comment: Please suggest if there is any other way to check for the validity of the form.

Comment: You'll need to do more debugging, testing your input and variables each step along the way in your view, for a start.

Comment: At first, I am checking with only one task to see if the allocation functionality works. I create one task using create functionality(,which is not allocated at first) and then I allocate it to one of the members. ```request.POST``` has the newly created task details which has not been allocated to any member yet. ```unallocated_tasks``` contains the queryset  containing details of the task not assigned/allocated

Comment: you don't have to close `input` tag because it's self closing tag eg. `<input type="submit" />`